# Is there a way to get event from mobile OS "upload menu"?

Tags: javascript, input, file-upload

Is there a way to track what the user does inside the native "upload" menu on his iPhone / Android?

I want to close the upload modal if the user closes this menu - but didn't find any way to track its state. Is there even a way to do it in a browser with JS?

[image]